# JQuery: Append Div and html slowly with effect

Tags: jquery

i am fetching data using ajax.

```
  <ul class="products">

  <li>Row1</li>

  <li>Row1</li>

  <li>Row1</li>

  <li>Row1</li>

  </ul>
```

when user click on li the li will append.

```
   jQuery(function(){

  jQuery('li').click(function(){

  jQuery('.products').append('<li class="new-rows"></li>');

  jQuery('.new-rows').html(dd , 500);

  });

 });
```

now what i am looking for is new generated li display slowly.

here dd is  the content getting from another page using ajax;

check this fiddle  :  http://jsfiddle.net/adHvb/2/

Comment: try this `jQuery('.products').append('<li style="display:none" class="new-rows"></li>').children("li:last").fadeIn(500);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/adHvb/6/

**JS:-**

```
jQuery('li').click(function () {
      dd = 'baba';
      var liData = '<li class="new-rows" style="display:none;"></li>';
      $(liData).appendTo('.products').fadeIn('slow');

      jQuery('.new-rows').html(dd, 500);
  });
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.i want to make it more slowly. is it possible to apply seconds to display it more slowly.

Comment: @JackTorris `$(liData).appendTo('.products').fadeIn(3000);` Change the value depending upon your requirement. http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/adHvb/9/

Comment: is it possible to make append slow. actually i am getting data using ajax so in my case it is not working .

Comment: can we make slow   jQuery('.new-rows').html(dd);  ??

Comment: thank you very much... it works now.. jQuery('.new-rows').hide().html(dd).fadeIn(3000);  but why .hide() is required here?

Comment: See [fadeIn docs](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/). It requires the element to be initially hidden, either by setting `style="display:none;"` or using jquery `.hide()`, in order for it to work.

Answer (score 7):

All the answers here regarding animation and effects are really good but I am mostly concern about the fetching part since you didn't include that. **Do you fetch the data on the start(document ready) or  only when `<li>` is clicked?**

If you fetch the data when the `<li>` `click()` event is fired you cannot just set a **specific delay for the animation**. What if it took some time to fetch the data?

I think you should do the appending and animation on [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) `success` function.

```
jQuery('li').click(function(){
    var $newRow = jQuery('<li class="new-rows"></li>');

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'type',
        url: 'url',
        data: data,
        success: function(dd){
            $newRow.html(dd).appendTo('.products').hide().fadeIn(1000);     
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

use Animate jquery for good effect

```
 jQuery('li').click(function(){
  jQuery('.products').append('<li class="new-rows"></li>');
    $( ".new-rows" ).animate({
         opacity: 0.25 //use more parameter for effect
    }, 5000, function() {
         jQuery('.new-rows').html(dd);
       // Animation complete.
   });
```

});

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery('li').click(function(){
dd = 'baba';
$('<li style="display:none;" class="new-rows"></li>').appendTo('.products').fadeIn('slow');
jQuery('.new-rows').html(dd , 500);});
```